# How to split value into multiple rows?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like that

```
     keytype   keyvalue
----------------------------
     type1     st1,st2,st3
--------------------------------
      type2    ts1,ts2,ts3
```

i want to insert data into a temporary table like that

```
    type1   type2
------------------------
    st1     ts1
-----------------
    st2     ts2
--------------------
    st3     ts3
```

how can i do.Please tell me.Thanks

Comment: Why are you jamming JSON into a single column? And do you only ever have 2 keytypes, or does this need to accommodate for any number of source rows? What do you want to happen when one of your JSON strings has 3 items and another has 4 items?

Answer (score 2):

You should store this data relationally instead of storing multiple pieces of data munged together in a CSV string. If you can't fix the design, then here's one way to do it, but it makes a couple of assumptions: (a) you only want two types (b) the types have the same number of comma-separated values. Not terribly cumbersome to extend if there are more than two rows, but unless you want to revert to really tedious dynamic SQL, you need to know how many there are in advance.

First, create an ordered split function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitStrings_Ordered]
(
    @List       NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @Delimiter  NVARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS
    RETURN (SELECT [Index] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Number), Item 
    FROM (SELECT Number, Item = SUBSTRING(@List, Number, 
      CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @List + @Delimiter, Number) - Number)
     FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY s1.[object_id])
      FROM sys.all_objects AS s1 CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS s2) AS n(Number)
      WHERE Number <= CONVERT(INT, LEN(@List))
      AND SUBSTRING(@Delimiter + @List, Number, LEN(@Delimiter)) = @Delimiter
    ) AS y);
GO
```

Then, assuming you have a table like this:

```
DECLARE @x TABLE(keytype VARCHAR(32), keyvalue VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT @x VALUES('type1','st1,st2,st3'),('type2','ts1,ts2,ts3');
```

You can join two CTEs that use a `CROSS APPLY` against the source table:

```
;WITH t1 AS 
(
  SELECT s.[Index], s.Item FROM @x AS x 
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered(x.keyvalue, ',') AS s 
  WHERE x.keytype = 'type1'
), t2 AS 
(
  SELECT s.[Index], s.Item FROM @x AS x 
  CROSS APPLY dbo.SplitStrings_Ordered(x.keyvalue, ',') AS s 
  WHERE x.keytype = 'type2'
)
-- INSERT #some_temp_table(columns)
SELECT type1 = t1.Item, type2 = t2.Item 
  FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2 ON t1.[Index] = t2.[Index]
  ORDER BY t1.[Index];
```